# How to detect field annotations when passed as parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

I have this code:

```
private static class MyObj {
    @NoConnection private static Object obj = new Object();
    public static boolean test() {
        return AnnotationDetector.isAnnotated(obj);
    }
}
```

The annotation detector works as follows:

```
private static class AnnotationDetector {
    public static boolean isAnnotated(Object object) {
        return object.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(NoConnection.class);
    }
}
```

It appears that there is no way to sense if the passed object has annotations. How do I rewrite the `AnnotationDetector` so that is works correctly?

Comment: Does your `NoConnection` annotation have the correct retention policy? `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Comment: `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` yes

Comment: As you say correctly yourself, it’s a **field** annotation, not a value annotation. So you can’t detect whether the object has the annotation, because the object has no annotation. The same object reference can be stored in a number of different fields having the annotation or not or even having the annotation with different values…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to detect the annotation in your case, because annotations are not bound to the values, they bound to the elements of your program (fields, methods, method parameters, etc.). The only thing you can do is to pass such element to the `isAnnotated` method (it's called [`AnnotatedElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html)):

```
static class MyObj {
    @NoConnection private static Object obj = new Object();

    public static boolean test() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        return AnnotationDetector.isAnnotated(MyObj.class.getDeclaredField("obj"));
    }
}

private static class AnnotationDetector {
    public static boolean isAnnotated(AnnotatedElement f) {
        return f.isAnnotationPresent(NoConnection.class);
    }
}
```